# tftpd on xinetd, not able to serve files Error `tftpd: unknown option -?`

Tags: networking, permissions, tftp, xinetd

I'm trying to serve a connection of tftpd (using xinetd) and I'm getting this error

```
$ sudo systemctl status xinetd
"tftpd[18566]: unknown option -?"
```

After establishing the connection from a the remote host, When attempting to get a file (or any other action) .
I dont know what may be wrong as I setted all the permissions and everything according to the tutorial

```
sudo apt-get install xinetd tftpd tftp
sudo mkdir -p /etc/xinetd.d/
sudo touch /etc/xinetd.d/tftp

sudo vim /etc/xinetd.d/tftp
##copy the text below
service tftp
{
protocol = udp
port = 69
socket_type = dgram
wait = yes
user = nobody
server = /usr/sbin/in.tftpd
server_args = /srv/tftp
disable = no
}


sudo mkdir /srv/tftpd
sudo cp ~/Downloads/openwrt-18.06.1-ar71xx-generic-wndr3800-squashfs-factory.img /srv/tftp
sudo chmod -R 777 /srv/tftp
sudo chown -R nobody /srv/tftp
sudo systemctl restart xinetd.service
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, for some reason I couldn't make work the `tftpd` included on the repositories "bunbled" with xinetd.
I've found my way though with opentftpd which a brief tutorial can be explaint on this tutorial. Thisone runs outside xinetd, and it does work
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K5yOBr3uoGs

```
wget http://downloads.sourceforge.net/proj...

tar xvf opentftpspV1.66.tar.gz
cd opentftp/
g++ opentftpd.cpp -oopentftpd -lpthread
mkdir /home/pi/files
chmod  777 /home/pi/files/
sudo bash
cp opentftpd /usr/bin/
vi /etc/opentftp.ini

## File contents ##
[LISTEN-ON]

[HOME]
/home/pi/files

[TFTP-OPTIONS]
username=pi
ThreadPoolSize=10
Read=Y
Write=Y
Overwrite=Y
##################

/usr/bin/opentftpd -i /etc/opentftp.ini
```